# Need to delete the references of a .m file and then add them again iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

I changed the `prefix header` name of my .h file in my Xcode project in several places, then changed the header back to its original. It seems that I have messed with my source or something. When attempting to control-click-drag from a UIButton to my .h file in order to create an **IBAction**,

I get the following error:

```
Could not insert new action connection: Could not insert source code into document at 
URL file://localhost/Users/Myuser/file/filename/projectname/SGLoginHomeViewController.m 
because it does not contain a class interface for the class named SGLoginHomeViewController
```

Once again I am attempting to create a new **IBAction** in the class file SGLoginHomeViewController.h

I believe that I need to delete the references and then add them back, but how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this:-

```
To Delete reference:_
1. Right click on your .h or .m file. 
2. Click on "Delete". A pop up will open.
3. Click on "Remove reference". Your file reference has been deleted.

To add it again:-
1. Right click on your project. 
2. Click on "Add files to 'YourProjectName'". 
3. A pop up will open. Select you file & Click Add.
Note:- Make sure "Copy items into destination group's folder(if needed)" is unchecked.
```

Comment: Ok I did that, but now I cannot add my file back. It is greyed out, was I supposed to save the file to a different location other than the project?

Comment: As it is in gray color, then it means it is added in the project.

Comment: Create a folder inside your project location and then add this folder into your xcode project.

Comment: No it is not. I'm sorry but I'm not entirely sure how to follow the steps in the comment above. I'm pretty new to programming

Comment: ok. Follow me:- 1. In finder, go to the folder where your project is saved. 2. You'll find one file named "YourProjectName.xcodeproj" and a folder with same name i.e "YourProjectName". 3. Go to "YourProjectName" folder. 4. Create a new folder named "New". 5. Copy that file i.e yourViewController.h or .m into this folder. 6. Now, open project in xcode. 7. Right click on project name which on left pane. 8. Click on "Add files to yourProject". 9. Add the folder named "New" that we have created in step no. 4.. Make sure "Copy items into destination folder" is unchecked.